# Condensing identical functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a bit of JavaScript to help condense this jQuery set of functions (numbered 1 through 7) ...

```
    $('.project-1 img').hover(function() {
      $('#id1').slideToggle();
    });
    $('.project-2 img').hover(function() {
      $('#id2').slideToggle();
    });
    ...
    $('.project-7 img').hover(function() {
      $('#id7').slideToggle();
    });
```

I tried this following bit of code, but it only targets `#id7` with `slideToggle`...

```
    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
      var projectNum = '.project-' + i + ' img';
      var idNum = '#id' + i;
      $(projectNum).hover(function() {
        $(idNum).slideToggle();
      });
    };
```

How do I condense the code into something cleaner?  Thanks!

Comment: Consider posting to code review?

Comment: Ahhh... The old loop-and-a-closure problem.

Comment: This may be okay for Code Review if a) the code works b) the code isn't hypothetical or incomplete in any way

Comment: You have the number you need in the class attribute, so just use a regex to extract it. `this.className.match(/project-(\d+)/)[1]` So then all you need a common class to use to select the group of elements in the first place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: You can avoid the use of an ugly loop/closure completely here if you use DRY principles - ie. common classes, data attributes for unique data and a single event handler

Comment: ...while the duplicate is indeed related to the OP's attempt, I don't think that's really the core of the question. The attempted solution isn't a great approach here. But then at its core it is off-topic.

Comment: Part of your problem is that you are using what appears to be a unique identifier for the class attribute, eg `project-1, project-2`, etc, when classes should be more generic. If each of these elements had a common set of classes, like `class='project img'`, then you could use a selector that referenced all of them, like `$('project img').hover`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenters above have correctly diagnosed the problem. Here's a fix:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    $('.project-' + i + ' img').hover(function () {
      $('#id' + i).slideToggle();
    });
  })(i);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

While a loop would work (if you fix the closure problem) a much better solution would be to instead use DRY principles to attach a single event handler which would work for all `img` elements and avoid the need for any loops or closures at all. Try this:

```
<div class="project">
    <img src="foo.jpg" data-target="#id1" />
</div>
<div class="project">
    <img src="bar.jpg" data-target="#id2" />
</div>
<!-- and so on... -->

<div id="id1">Lorem</div>
<div id="id2">Ipsum</div>
<!-- and so on... -->
```

```js
$('.project img').hover(function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Nice. Much better to address the ultimate question than patching a sub-optimal attempt.

Comment: Neat!  I didn't even know this was a possibility.